# Powershell script for data parsing

Tags: parsing, powershell

I am looking for a Powershell script that could help me for this task:

Got data like this:

```
"No.","time","1-1","1-2","1-3","1-4","1-5","1-6","1-7","1-8","1-9","1-10","1-11","1-12","1-13","1-14","1-15","5-1","5-2","5-3","5-4","5-5","5-6","5-7","5-8","5-9","5-11","5-13","5-15","9-1","9-3","9-5","9-7","9-8","9-9","13-1","13-2","13-3","13-4","13-5","13-6","13-7","13-8","13-9","13-10","17-1","17-2","17-3","17-4","17-5","17-6","17-7","17-8","17-9","E1-1","00:FE:FFX(X2049-1)","00:00:8DX(X2050-1)","00:00:8CX(X2051-1)","00:00:8BX(X2052-1)","00:00:8EX(X2053-1)","00:00:8FX(X2054-1)","00:00:97X(X2055-1)","00:00:96X(X2056-1)","00:00:92X(X2057-1)","00:00:99X(X2058-1)","00:00:98X(X2059-1)","00:00:94X(X2060-1)","00:00:93X(X2061-1)","00:00:90X(X2062-1)","00:00:95X(X2063-1)","00:00:91X(X2064-1)","00:00:9FX(X2065-1)","00:00:9CX(X2066-1)","00:00:A0X(X2067-1)","00:00:A1X(X2068-1)","00:00:9AX(X2069-1)","00:00:9EX(X2070-1)","00:00:A5X(X2071-1)","00:00:A3X(X2072-1)","00:00:A4X(X2073-1)","00:00:9BX(X2074-1)","00:00:A2X(X2075-1)","00:02:D2X(X2076-1)","00:00:A6X(X2077-1)","00:00:A7X(X2078-1)","00:01:0CX(X2079-1)","00:60:48X(X2080-1)","00:00:B2X(X2081-1)","00:02:B4X(X2082-1)","00:02:43X(X2083-1)","00:00:AEX(X2084-1)","00:00:ADX(X2085-1)","00:02:E4X(X2086-1)","00:02:BDX(X2087-1)","00:00:B1X(X2088-1)","00:00:DFX(X2089-1)","00:00:B3X(X2090-1)","00:60:40X(X2091-1)","00:60:41X(X2092-1)","00:00:B5X(X2093-1)","00:00:B7X(X2094-1)","00:00:C3X(X2095-1)","00:60:42X(X2096-1)","00:00:C9X(X2097-1)","00:00:C2X(X2098-1)","00:00:C1X(X2099-1)","00:00:C4X(X2100-1)","00:00:B4X(X2101-1)","00:00:2FX(X2102-1)","00:00:BAX(X2103-1)","00:00:B6X(X2104-1)","00:00:BFX(X2105-1)","00:00:C8X(X2106-1)","00:00:D3X(X2107-1)","00:00:B8X(X2108-1)","00:00:C5X(X2109-1)","00:00:CFX(X2110-1)","00:00:CAX(X2111-1)","00:00:CCX(X2112-1)","00:60:43X(X2113-1)","00:00:D9X(X2114-1)","00:00:BCX(X2115-1)","00:00:A8X(X2116-1)","00:00:C7X(X2117-1)","00:00:D0X(X2118-1)","00:00:BBX(X2119-1)","00:01:3BX(X2120-1)","00:01:3EX(X2121-1)","00:00:BEX(X2122-1)","00:00:BDX(X2123-1)"
"1","2013/11/04 15:45",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1550,0,1010,58,81,73,197,91,275,286,378,44,58,101,140,41,66,144,107,62,17,36,8,46,76,98,-5,130,217,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,144,0,5,-5,-5,15,281,2859,-5,1,442,724,13,12,880,97,171,130,30,0,49,15,0,82,12,-5,0,443,0,55,64,1269,-5,-5,41,172
"2","2013/11/04 15:46",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1710,0,903,57,91,42,172,95,609,281,274,34,126,384,254,39,49,315,90,46,20,197,8,71,61,89,-5,247,220,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,126,0,12,-5,-5,16,258,3298,-5,4,647,716,1,9,868,101,208,26,30,0,53,17,0,89,9,-5,0,448,0,36,68,1394,-5,-5,39,67
"3","2013/11/04 15:47",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1548,0,853,55,91,71,193,145,103,269,272,38,77,142,184,39,180,796,85,44,18,517,7,101,64,88,-5,549,138,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,156,0,3,-5,-5,22,260,2496,-5,18,448,620,15,6,789,194,239,66,96,0,31,13,0,164,8,-5,0,344,0,33,55,1121,-5,-5,72,121
"4","2013/11/04 15:48",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1558,0,874,34,76,38,201,550,113,288,158,18,64,116,458,42,51,127,90,44,16,50,6,69,66,102,-5,116,294,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,116,0,1,-5,-5,7,210,3038,-5,5,81,553,5,6,834,53,248,26,88,0,36,17,0,17,9,-5,0,78,0,206,55,1450,-5,-5,45,92
"5","2013/11/04 15:49",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1620,0,900,39,88,37,229,171,211,311,264,23,104,128,506,42,201,50,98,46,19,62,6,61,59,102,-5,102,306,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,126,0,3,-5,-5,16,241,3235,-5,11,353,740,8,8,818,68,244,24,111,0,21,14,0,19,10,-5,0,91,0,93,63,1567,-5,-5,50,103
"6","2013/11/04 15:50",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1745,0,907,44,83,37,189,213,293,265,130,47,68,514,222,42,106,142,92,62,18,338,6,49,79,88,-5,140,231,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,135,0,5,-5,-5,43,376,3095,-5,1,300,656,1,9,790,91,263,54,103,0,29,14,0,15,11,-5,0,91,0,81,58,1579,-5,-5,57,104
"7","2013/11/04 15:51",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1786,0,972,45,84,55,195,110,798,324,150,31,191,1406,332,1126,225,60,87,57,70,203,7,45,62,81,-5,112,235,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,121,0,60,-5,-5,4,354,3378,-5,2,421,629,2,136,737,81,196,128,92,0,21,16,0,18,13,-5,0,71,0,90,55,1184,-5,-5,41,170
"8","2013/11/04 15:52",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1704,0,928,31,87,38,199,111,286,341,195,24,299,1065,292,329,60,54,87,45,18,54,6,67,72,89,-5,102,204,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,172,0,22,-5,-5,5,494,3337,-5,9,169,792,6,15,764,159,227,45,92,0,36,16,0,16,11,-5,0,78,0,93,65,1706,-5,-5,61,81
"9","2013/11/04 15:53",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1494,0,857,28,112,47,188,649,111,318,153,21,87,445,288,34,45,52,87,44,29,94,10,61,74,98,-5,152,129,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,172,0,1,-5,-5,10,324,3371,-5,1,46,625,3,7,824,54,216,25,85,0,34,17,0,34,12,-5,0,85,0,104,66,1578,-5,-5,32,40
"10","2013/11/04 15:54",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1565,0,850,80,116,38,217,98,127,370,329,174,96,251,184,37,107,66,380,43,18,92,8,41,65,96,-5,104,231,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,162,0,2,-5,-5,6,272,3743,-5,11,314,545,7,5,962,66,5,20,28,0,13,15,0,17,11,-5,0,40,0,149,65,1419,-5,-5,31,63
"11","2013/11/04 15:55",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1650,0,841,55,77,37,168,80,133,291,286,17,64,138,152,43,57,936,97,57,16,112,8,52,72,103,-5,134,407,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,129,0,5,-5,-5,2,274,3401,-5,3,297,522,2,8,805,96,5,23,23,0,16,14,0,15,12,-5,0,37,0,186,74,1623,-5,-5,14,45
"12","2013/11/04 15:56",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1471,0,826,42,81,38,162,92,477,284,191,32,68,130,144,45,66,244,100,63,16,146,14,139,102,96,-5,104,302,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,127,0,10,-5,-5,8,298,3363,-5,2,440,582,3,18,1010,79,8,68,19,0,14,15,0,15,11,-5,0,45,0,129,68,1539,-5,-5,4,93
"13","2013/11/04 15:57",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,1035,0,1002,39,308,36,226,101,104,269,185,24,91,122,137,46,140,59,87,49,18,273,7,156,75,87,-5,113,145,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,202,0,3,-5,-5,6,214,3794,-5,9,192,500,4,18,1095,161,90,142,84,0,15,15,0,25,17,-5,0,59,0,207,59,1563,-5,-5,29,164
"14","2013/11/04 15:58",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,707,0,968,33,230,37,179,139,138,303,255,21,92,104,161,234,67,55,100,43,18,168,6,145,87,93,-5,126,294,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,140,0,2,-5,-5,13,305,3448,-5,1,262,648,4,30,928,58,281,51,163,0,19,18,0,40,17,-5,0,155,0,90,50,1631,-5,-5,15,60
"15","2013/11/04 15:59",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-5,-5,-5,761,0,954,58,103,41,176,79,107,310,109,20,86,142,146,846,51,68,91,50,18,184,6,45,71,96,-5,109,142,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,254,0,3,-5,-5,6,276,3513,-5,3,171,545,4,4,958,51,91,34,60,0,27,16,0,22,12,-5,0,62,0,91,52,1651,-5,-5,12,51
"No.","time","00:01:3CX(X2124-1)","00:00:C0X(X2125-1)","00:00:C6X(X2126-1)","00:01:04X(X2127-1)","00:01:08X(X2128-1)","00:00:DBX(X2129-1)","00:01:B9X(X2130-1)","00:00:DDX(X2131-1)","00:00:DCX(X2132-1)","00:01:64X(X2133-1)","00:00:E0X(X2134-1)","00:00:E1X(X2135-1)","00:00:E2X(X2136-1)","00:00:E6X(X2137-1)","00:00:E8X(X2138-1)","00:00:E5X(X2139-1)","00:00:E4X(X2140-1)","00:00:E3X(X2141-1)","00:00:E7X(X2142-1)","00:00:E9X(X2143-1)","00:00:CEX(X2144-1)","00:00:D8X(X2145-1)","00:00:AAX(X2146-1)","00:00:EDX(X2147-1)","00:60:3FX(X2148-1)","00:00:F7X(X2149-1)","00:00:31X(X2150-1)","00:00:D6X(X2151-1)","00:00:D7X(X2152-1)","00:00:EEX(X2153-1)","00:00:EFX(X2154-1)","00:60:46X(X2155-1)","00:00:F0X(X2156-1)","00:00:F1X(X2157-1)","00:00:ECX(X2158-1)","00:00:F3X(X2159-1)","00:00:EBX(X2160-1)","00:00:F4X(X2161-1)","00:00:32X(X2162-1)","00:01:86X(X2163-1)","00:00:2BX(X2164-1)","00:02:10X(X2165-1)","00:02:11X(X2166-1)","00:00:2CX(X2167-1)","00:01:0AX(X2168-1)","00:01:0BX(X2169-1)","00:00:A9X(X2170-1)","00:60:02X(X2171-1)","00:60:01X(X2172-1)","00:60:03X(X2173-1)","00:60:04X(X2174-1)","00:60:05X(X2175-1)","00:60:06X(X2176-1)","00:60:07X(X2177-1)","00:60:08X(X2178-1)","00:60:09X(X2179-1)","00:60:0AX(X2180-1)","00:60:00X(X2181-1)","00:60:3EX(X2182-1)","00:01:06X(X2183-1)","00:01:0DX(X2184-1)","00:01:07X(X2185-1)","00:01:05X(X2186-1)","00:02:7BX(X2187-1)","00:02:7CX(X2188-1)","00:02:B5X(X2189-1)","00:02:E5X(X2190-1)","00:02:0FX(X2191-1)","00:01:0EX(X2192-1)","00:01:11X(X2193-1)","00:01:14X(X2194-1)","00:01:10X(X2195-1)","00:01:12X(X2196-1)","00:01:13X(X2197-1)","00:01:09X(X2198-1)","00:00:FBX(X2199-1)","00:00:33X(X2200-1)","00:01:0FX(X2201-1)","00:01:27X(X2202-1)","00:01:15X(X2203-1)","00:01:1DX(X2204-1)","00:01:1BX(X2205-1)","00:01:1AX(X2206-1)","00:01:1CX(X2207-1)","00:02:4CX(X2208-1)","00:01:39X(X2209-1)","00:01:16X(X2210-1)","00:01:38X(X2211-1)","00:02:E7X(X2212-1)","00:01:18X(X2213-1)","00:00:FEX(X2214-1)","00:01:19X(X2215-1)","00:00:FDX(X2216-1)","00:00:FFX(X2217-1)","00:01:29X(X2218-1)","00:01:28X(X2219-1)","00:01:17X(X2220-1)","00:01:2DX(X2221-1)","00:01:2EX(X2222-1)","00:01:2FX(X2223-1)","00:01:2BX(X2224-1)","00:01:2CX(X2225-1)","00:60:0BX(X2226-1)","00:02:07X(X2227-1)","00:60:0FX(X2228-1)","00:60:0CX(X2229-1)","00:60:0DX(X2230-1)","00:01:00X(X2231-1)","00:01:4CX(X2232-1)","00:01:56X(X2233-1)","00:01:61X(X2234-1)","00:01:4EX(X2235-1)","00:01:55X(X2236-1)","00:01:58X(X2237-1)","00:01:59X(X2238-1)","00:01:52X(X2239-1)","00:01:5DX(X2240-1)","00:01:60X(X2241-1)","00:01:4DX(X2242-1)","00:01:5AX(X2243-1)","00:01:54X(X2244-1)","00:01:46X(X2245-1)","00:01:5EX(X2246-1)","00:01:5CX(X2247-1)","00:01:49X(X2248-1)","00:01:4AX(X2249-1)","00:01:50X(X2250-1)","00:01:4BX(X2251-1)"
"1","2013/11/04 15:45",-5,9,62,-5,-5,0,-5,0,0,-5,7,0,0,40,21,55,21,79,24,203,3,0,88,51,-5,0,2,272,15,1967,51,-5,61,58,31,243,24,0,3,-5,0,-5,-5,13,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,0,-5,1,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5
"2","2013/11/04 15:46",-5,10,47,-5,-5,0,-5,0,0,-5,7,0,0,45,24,68,25,94,24,185,3,0,93,40,-5,0,3,285,116,2195,75,-5,117,70,41,216,27,0,3,-5,0,-5,-5,13,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,9,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,35,-5,24,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5
"3","2013/11/04 15:47",-5,19,111,-5,-5,0,-5,0,0,-5,2,0,0,44,30,62,24,91,32,190,1,0,93,121,-5,0,3,346,283,1534,10,-5,93,29,32,218,14,0,3,-5,0,-5,-5,12,-5,-5,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,34,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,125,-5,74,0,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5
...
... etc etc ...
```

Its a CSV file which seems to be split when the number of columns > 130: next columns are added to the file with new lines.
I don't know the number of columns which is dynamic, but I always have 1 Header Line + 15 Results followed by 1 Header Line + 15 Results and so on a certain number of times.

What I'm looking is reserve this split thing and have one correct CSV file that I can add into Splunk later. That means EACH LINE HAVE ONE DISTINCT TIME (And No.) so my new file much have only 16 lines. (1 Header Line + 15 Results, 1 by minute)

So I need to append :

- all the (16+1)*n lines (n belongs to 1,EndOfFile) to the 1rst line
  without the first 2 columns (No and Time are the same)
- all the
  (16+2)*n lines to the 2nd line without the first 2 columns (No and
  Time are the same)
- all the (16+3)*n lines to the 3nd line without the
  first 2 columns (No and Time are the same)
- etc etc...

If someone can help me with this script that would be awesome !

**EDIT**: Here's where I am but no success:

```
Import-Csv .\data.txt |Group-Object -Property No.,time |% {
  $text = $_.name+","
  $text += ($_.group | % {$i=0;$j=$_.count}{$i++ ; ($_|%{$_.toString() + ","})*($j-$i -gt 0)})
  $text += "`n"
  Write-Output $text  
}
```

**EDIT 2**: My problem is that I got an hashtable but I don't know any Names to get all the elements. I tried with `getEnumerator()` without success :

Method invocation failed because `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` doesn't contain a method named 'getEnumerator'.

```
Import-Csv .\data.txt |Group-Object -Property No.,time  |% {
  $text = $_.name+","
  $text += ($_.group | % {$i=0;$j=$_.count}{$i++ ; ($_.GetEnumerator()|%{$_ + ","})*($j-$i -gt 0)})
  $text += "`n"
  Write-Output $text  
}
```

If I put a column name like "1-1" instead of `getEnumerator()` its working but I can't do that for all columns since I don't know the names.

Comment: Try using: "Import-Csv <filename.csv> | Group-Object -Property No., time" should get you started...

Comment: I updated my question. My problem is that I dont know the header names because they are dynamic so I cant replace de to_string() by a property.

Comment: I think the reason you are being down voted is because you are asking for a solution rather than showing what you have tried and where you are having problems, these type of questions either get closed down or are of little use to other developers.  I can see you have posted an update which is beginning to be on the right line but you haven't explained what 'No Success' means, for example 'you were expecting x but got y'.  To help you along your way the group object is a hashtable, so investigate http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx.

Comment: A hash table has two members key and value, you should be able to enumerate the key value pairs to build your new csv.

Comment: Problem is that Powershell says its not an hashtable but an System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject 
And sorry for past french it came without attention.

Tried ($i | Format-List | Out-String) but not ok with the format

Comment: I think I will be ok adding -AsHashTable  to Group-Object. That what I was looking for but seems I Cant manage to make people understand me. Anyways thnks for your help. Will put the answer when I'll be done

Comment: And no, it dosnt change the problem I still have all my columns as properties of an object instead of an hashtable, so I cant access them without knowing exactly the name of each column

Comment: $object.psobject.properties | select -expand name will get you a list of all the property names of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used get-content and array treatment its a lot more easier than trying to get these **** cmd-let working...

```
$ofs = ',' # ! Variable Interne utilisée pour le cast de [string] venant d'un [array], définit le séparateur


#Lecture des fichiers en entrée
$txt = gc .\data.txt
if($txt -is [system.array]){

    #Declaration des variables
    $res = @()
    $count = 0

    #Traitement
    foreach ($line in $txt) { #On traite toutes les lignes du fichier
        $count++              #On incremente le compteur de lignes

        If($count-le 16) {    #Les 16 premieres lignes [1 Header + 15 Datas row]
            $res += $line+"," #sont copiées telles quelles

        } else {                                        #Pour toutes les lignes suivantes [17,+inf]
            $newline = $line.Split(',')[2..500]         #On supprime leur deux premières colonnes
            $res[($count%16)-1] += [string] $newline        #On les ajoute aux 16 premières lignes avec Mod[16]
        }
    }

    #Ecriture des fichiers de sortie
    $res
}
```